# Is there any open source software for Linux that will create a full file index and allow for querying of that index?

Tags: search, lucene, indexer

I essentially am looking for a piece of software for my own server similar to how Google works.  I would like to be able to index my videos, pictures, music, and documents and have them searchable from a web page (similar to Google).  I am not opposed to working this, I just haven't been able to find any full featured software that would do this, just pieces.

I have seen the following that don't really fit my needs :

- **Recoll** (http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) seems like a great product, however it only indexes documents.
- **Tracker** (https://projects.gnome.org/tracker/)  This also seems like a good product, it doesn't have a web frontent, but it seems like I could come up with that if I really wanted to add it.  The parts that concern me here are separation of code, I would ideally just like a service that the frontend could make a request to that wouldn't have any UI dependencies.

These are the two main pieces that I have found, there are definitely technologies out there that would help (such as Apache Lucene). But my main question, is this something that I should write myself?  I do have the knowledge to go about this, and I fully plan on doing it if that is what needs to happen, I just want to know if maybe there are some existing technologies that I am missing.